# Azure Function: Queue Trigger removes message, but doesn't fire

Tags: azure, message-queue

I have a Azure Function using Queue Trigger, the method looks like this

```
[FunctionName("ProcessNotifications")]
public static async Task ExecuteAsync(
    [QueueTrigger("sharepointnotifications", Connection = "QueueConnectionString")] CloudQueueMessage queueMessage,
    ILogger logger,
    ExecutionContext context)
{
    logger.LogInformation("Message received..");
    var azureFuncContext = InitializationService.Initialize(context.FunctionAppDirectory, logger);
    await ExecuteInternalAsync(queueMessage, logger, azureFuncContext);
}
```

I'm using a Azure Storage Queue Service, which acts a queue. What's really interesting: In around 80% of the time, when a new message arrives, it is removed, but the Azure Function is not called. I've also removed all my code except the LogInformation to assure it's not an internal problem, but even then, it doesn't work.

Googling about this issue, I found this thread: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3493

But this error seems different, since in this case, the message remains on the queue, but in my case the message is removed, but just nothing is happening.

To assure the problem isn't about the messages, I've stopped the Azure Function and, as expected, the messages are put in the queue.

Unfortunately, I really can't get more insights in the issues, as no warnings or such are thrown. The GitHub issue is still active, therefore I'm inclined to believe there is a problem, but having unreliable queue triggers would be such a big issue, I'm sure it would be fixed by now.

Is there any possibility to get more information about this?

Comment: is the message appearing in the poison queue ?.  Rather than using CloudObjectMessage could use JObject and serialize the message in function, we had this before and it was a serialization issue which seems to be resolved in v2 functions.  Does it trigger if you debug locally by dropping a message on the queue manually.

Comment: @MarkWest Thank you very much. Short question: Would I need to create the poison queue by myself for a storage account queue? I've created one by myself now, but I think there is no out of the box poison queue handling at all (from what I've found googling)

Comment: poison queues are created automatically when an exception is thrown, hmm looking at your code, it should have try..catch and then throw any exception, the message will then be put on poison queue and you should see exception logged, this may give you the root cause of problem

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with queue triggers.  It seems to be the result of "log sampling."
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling).

I just ran up the VS Code sample queue trigger app with the same result.  As a test, I logged a line (python) 100x in a loop, and it finally *was* displayed, but only 4x.  So it is clearly missing a lot of log entries.

My recommendation is to debug locally and if it works there, assume it's working in Azure until your function does something you can monitor directly (i.e, by the result, not by watching the logs.)

This can be a real time waster until you realize the App Insights logs are probably just missing the action.